# Changing the RoR SQL call to NAME instead of *

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Being that it is better to call a SQL database with the specific item, for example:

Bad:

```
SELECT * FROM tblUsers
```

Good:

```
SELECT email FROM tblUsers
```

How would I do this in RoR to make it explicitly perform the latter example?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming your `tblUsers` table is used by `User` model, you should do

```
User.all(:select => "email")
```